# Saleor. When I ran the `docker-compose up -d` I got this error message

Tags: docker

https://getsaleor.com/

`Starting type checking and linting service...`
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
(node:18) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

Comment: How much RAM do you have? I was having the same issue and it was suggested that I might not have enough RAM. I bumped my RAM up to 2GB (from 512MB) and it "just works"... See https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/4297